# Now that TestFlight Live became private FlightPath beta, can we still leave TestFlight in production builds?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, flightpath

This [document](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829571-does-the-sdk-support-production-builds-) explains that it is OK to leave TestFlight SDK in a production build for the App Store.

But the TestFlight Live they're talking about turned into a new service called FlightPath, which happens to be in private beta. I applied for it weeks ago and never got access. With this change, can I still make my app future-proof and FlightPath compatible by leaving the TestFlight SDK in the App Store build or should I remove it and wait until I get access to FlightPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it should be ok .. just don't set the UniqueIdentifier for [TestFlight takeOff:]

Comment: Any idea what happens if leave it set ?

Comment: the devices can't be matched to users -> all the reports: XY started session, will be as marked anonymous instead